# Export PNGs from Photoshop when on Retina display

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, mac, retina

I am on a 5k iMac and creating thumbnails from screen shots for use in a website. In case it matters, my display resolution is set to 3200x1800 (less than the number of physical pixels of the display itself).

In Photoshop I have a layer that is 488x268 pixels. As I understand things, Photoshop is using physical display pixels in its measurement. So the layer is 488x268 physical pixels and quite small physically on screen (about the length from the tip of my thumb to its first knuckle).

When I `Export As... PNG` I experience the following:

1. Opening the file in quick preview (spacebar) shows the image at twice its physical size and blurred.
2. Opening the file in Preview app shows the image at the correct physical size but investigating info on it reveals that DPI information is saved, including DPI width and height.
3. Opening the file in a web browser (Chrome or Safari) shows the image at twice its physical size because the browser is using "CSS pixels" and thus doubling the 488x268 physical pixels into 976x536 for displaying the image.

It seems I am in a "chicken or the egg" situation whereby I cannot actually create an image in Photoshop that will look sharp and non-blurred in the browser. Whatever dimension the image is in Photoshop will be doubled in the browser.

**How can I properly size and export images and layers in Photoshop to keep them sharp in the browser?**

Here is one sample image, if it helps:

- https://arcpointgroup-luna.imgix.net/settings-style-cusps.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure this issue is not related to how you export the PNG from Photoshop. Browser don't take resolution (PPI) into account so only actual pixel dimensions matter. Doesn't the same thing happen with *any* PNG you try to open in Preview or a browser?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Photoshop.  It's down to your hardware and system display scaling. DPI/PPI is ignored by web browsers.

Comment: @Wolff Q: "Doesn't the same thing happen with any PNG you try to open in Preview or a browser?" A: No. See this example PNG from Wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png

Opening it directly in the browser shows it as expected (non-blurred). Furthermore, opening in Preview shows it at the same physical size as in the browser. Even further still, in Preview, there are no "DPI height and width" values for this image. I still think Photoshop is adding this information to the exported PNG and that is somehow effecting its display.

Comment: Strange. So if you open the example image from Wikipedia in Photoshop and save it under another name, *that* image is suddenly shown at double size in Preview and browser? (I'm glad I chose not to switch to a 4k+ monitor yet, those scaling problems seems *so* annoying. Also the problems with ui scaling and the likes.)

Comment: Btw, the example image in your post has resolution set to 144 PPI. I didn't think it would matter, but try to save it at 72 PPI instead, just to check.

Comment: @Wolff Basically, yes. Except what really occurs is that opening the Wikipedia image in Photoshop shows the image at half the size of the original because 800x600 in physical pixels on a 5k display is quite small. The browser is using a DPR value of 2 (seen via `window.devicePixelRatio`). So when I export the image from Photoshop as a PNG, it is then doubled from the PS version to then be the same size as the original in the browser and in Preview. It's difficult to tell if it's also blurry because the source image is quite sharp, but I suspect it is.

Comment: @Wolff Thank you for pointing that out. I did try at 72dpi and it's the same result. I just didn't mention that in my OP.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Let's use the same terminology: The true/original size of an image is the size you see in Photoshop where each pixel in the image takes up one pixel on screen. That the browser apparently uses CCS to scale up the image is unrelated to the image afaik. Except for perhaps resolution if things have recently changed. So the "quite small" image you see is the original size. What you say now is that if you resave the Wikipedia image it acts as expected? Which is different from when you save your own image that seems to be "double doubled"?

Comment: @Wolff My image isn't "double doubled", it's only "doubled once". The issue is that it's blurry. Why is this Wikipedia one not? Here is the original image in Preview and PS, both @ 100%: https://arcpointgroup-luna.imgix.net/dice.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134217/discussion-between-wolff-and-etipaced).